# TFJS save model to http with headers

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow.js

I am trying to save and upload a tfjs model with additional headers ( for class names ) using guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load with backend 
copied from https://gist.github.com/dsmilkov/1b6046fd6132d7408d5257b0976f7864 . 
But following the guide does not work as intended and stated in the guide. 
Where am I making a mistake? Thanks

My code for browser is:

```
const saveResult = await model.save(tf.io.http('http://localhost:5000/upload', {method: 'POST', headers: {'class': 'Dog'}}));
```

Code for the server is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import io

from flask import Flask, Response, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
import werkzeug.formparser

class ModelReceiver(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._model = None
    self._model_json_bytes = None
    self._model_json_writer = None
    self._weight_bytes = None
    self._weight_writer = None

  @property
  def model(self):
    self._model_json_writer.flush()
    self._weight_writer.flush()
    self._model_json_writer.seek(0)
    self._weight_writer.seek(0)

    json_content = self._model_json_bytes.read()
    weights_content = self._weight_bytes.read()
    return tfjs.converters.deserialize_keras_model(
        json_content,
        weight_data=[weights_content],
        use_unique_name_scope=True)

  def stream_factory(self,
                     total_content_length,
                     content_type,
                     filename,
                     content_length=None):
    # Note: this example code isnot* thread-safe.
    if filename == 'model.json':
      self._model_json_bytes = io.BytesIO()
      self._model_json_writer = io.BufferedWriter(self._model_json_bytes)
      return self._model_json_writer
    elif filename == 'model.weights.bin':
      self._weight_bytes = io.BytesIO()
      self._weight_writer = io.BufferedWriter(self._weight_bytes)
      return self._weight_writer


def main():
  app = Flask('model-server')
  CORS(app)
  app.config['CORS_HEADER'] = 'Content-Type'

  model_receiver = ModelReceiver()

  @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
  @cross_origin()
  def upload():
    print('headers are:')
    print(request.headers)
    print('Handling request...')
    werkzeug.formparser.parse_form_data(
        request.environ, stream_factory=model_receiver.stream_factory)
    print('Received model:')
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session():
      model = model_receiver.model
      model.summary()
      # You can perform `model.predict()`, `model.fit()`,
      # `model.evaluate()` etc. here.
    return Response(status=200)

  app.run('localhost', 5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: The request options needs to be in an object `{requestInit: config}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model.save` takes as paremeter a `url` and a config. The config contains the `requestInit` needed by the [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) api that is used under the hood.

The request will look as the following

```
model.save(url, {requestInit: {method: 'POST', headers: {'class': 'Dog'}}))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to store some auxiliary information (such as class labels) with the model, there is a relatively little-known feature of `tf.LayersModel` in TensorFlow.js that will make your life easier. It's simpler than using a header.

It is the `setUserDefinedMetadata()` and `getUserDefinedMetadata()` method.

On the JavaScript side, do:

```js
// The argument to setUserDefinedMetadata() can be any serializable JSON
// object of a reasonable size.
myModel.setUserDefinedMetadata({outputClassLabels: ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Turtle']});

// The user metadata is stored with the model itself. No need to specify 
// additional headers.
await model.save('http://localhost:5000/upload');
```

The server that receives the model artifacts can simply check the 'userDefinedMetadata' field of the JSON payload in the request.

Comment: this is nice feature! It could be very useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Much needed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the client side, where headers whould be used in this way

```
var myInit = { method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   'classes': ['class1', 'class2']
               }};

const saveResult = await model.save(tf.io.http(
    'http://localhost:5000/upload', loadOptions={requestInit: myInit}));
```